# How to run this module?

Tags: python, module

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   citcodownloader.pyproj
│   citcodownloader.sln
│   readme.md
│   requirements.txt
│
├───CitcoLoaders
│   │   helpers.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───tests
│   │   │   test_helpers.py
│   │   │   test_PositionLoader.py
│   │   │   test_tradeloader.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───test_files
│   │           cash_test_20180331.csv
│   │           Position_Download_read_test_2017-11-30.csv
│   │           trade_test_20180108.csv
│   │
│   └───TradeLoader
│       │   TradeLoader.py
│       │   __init__.py
│       │   __main__.py
```

I'm on the `CitcoLoaders` directory. This is inside my `__main__.py` from the `TradeLoader` folder:

`from CitcoLoaders.TradeLoader.TradeLoader import TradeLoader`

And `TradeLoader.py` is a class that transforms CSV files.

I'm trying to run it from the `CitcoLoaders` directory like this:

`python -m TradeLoader` but I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\cgrijalva\Source\Repos\citcodownloader\CitcoLoaders\TradeLoader\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from CitcoLoaders.TradeLoader.TradeLoader import TradeLoader
ImportError: No module named 'CitcoLoaders'
```

Am I on the wrong path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that you are on the right path.

Having a directory on your `sys.path` that's inside a package that you're using is not supported, and leads to all kinds of problems. And by default, your current working directory is added to your `sys.path`.

Plus, when you run `-m TradeLoader` from within this directory, it doesn't end up running as the sub-package `CitcoLoaders.TradeLoader`, but instead as the top-level package `TradeLoader`. Which means it doesn't have a parent package, but it's trying to access that non-existent parent package anyway, hence the exception.

So, `cd` up a level, and everything should work fine.

---

As a side note, you should consider writing a script at the top level (outside the package) that imports the module and calls some `main` function in it, rather than writing a module designed to be run with `-m`. If you're using `setuptools` (and you should be, for a package structure this complicated), it can do all the hard work for you, by automatically creating console scripts for entry points that you specify. It will make the scripts work properly whether you build in-place in a virtualenv, or `pip install` to a system with a crazy setup you never anticipated.

[The documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) is pretty involved, and focused more on reference than explanation, and even the [PyPA tutorial](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) doesn't explain things that well, but there are multiple helpful blog posts, like [this one by Chris Warrick](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/). (I've only briefly skimmed it, but looks good.)

Answer (score 0):

TradeLoader is a module inside CitcoLoaders. Try moving up a folder into C: and try running "python -m CitcoLoaders.TradeLoader".